# How can I open a webpage within a Java app and run my own javascript code 

Tags: java, javascript, bookmarklet

I would like to open a webpage and run a javascript code from within a java app.
For example I would like to open the page *www.mytestpage.com* and run the following javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("txtEmail").value="test@hotmail.com";
submit();
void(0);
```

This works in a browser...how can I do it programatically within a java app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's [Rhino JS engine](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) written in Java that you can run on app server such as Tomcat and feed JS to, however - it's not clear what are you trying to do with this?

There's also [Envjs simulated browser environment](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guide-1.0.x) which is based on Rhino but complete enough to run jQuery and/or Prototype

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) to execute JavaScript but you won't have a DOM available - i.e.  `document.getElementById()` would work.

You can use [HTML Unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (headless) or [WebDriver/Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) (Driving a browser) to execute JavaScript in an environment that has a DOM available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for but I assume that you want to write automated POST request. This can be done in with [Http Client library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). Only you have to set appropriate request (POST or GET) parameters.

Look at [examples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/) - with this library you can do basic authentication or post files too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, as we don't know the position of the Java program.
If that's a Java applet inside your page, you should look at Java<->JavaScript interaction, it works well.
If you need a separate Java program to control a browser, like sending a bookmarklet in the address bar (as one of your tags suggests), it is a bit harder (depends on target browser), perhaps look at the Robot class.

Answer (score 0):

DWR (and other frameworks) now support "reverse ajax."  The general idea is that you use one of three methods to communicate back to the client:

1. Comet (long-lived https session)
2. Polling
3. opportunistic / piggy-back (i.e. next time a request comes from the client, append your js call)

Regardless of method (which is typically a configuration-time decision and not a coding issue), you will have full access to any/all js calls you want to make.

Check out [the reference page from DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/reverse-ajax/index.html) to get a pretty good explanation.